# I am having error using Image cropper in my project

Tags: flutter

I am using image cropper dependency in my flutter project.

I am using `image_cropper: ^1.4.1,` And I am getting an error showing

```
Error: Member not found: 'ImageCropper.cropImage'.
      final croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is my code

```
Future<File?> cropImage(File imageFile) async {
    File? croppedFile;
    try {
      croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: imageFile.path,
          aspectRatioPresets: [
                  CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                  CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                  CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                  CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                  CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
                ],
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
              toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
              toolbarColor: accentColor,
              toolbarWidgetColor: white,
              initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
              lockAspectRatio: false),
          iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
            title: 'Cropper',
          ));

      return croppedFile;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return croppedFile;
  }
```

I don't know what is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `ImageCropper.cropImage` with `ImageCropper().cropImage`

Comment: Based on the documentation for image_cropper: ^1.4.1, My code above is the right syntax. When I try ImageCropper().cropImage, I am getting   'The static method 'cropImage' can't be accessed through an instance'.

Comment: True true, have u tried using a newer version of `image_cropper` ? like 1.5.0 ?

Comment: I am still getting same error

Comment: You are using `ImageCropper().cropImage` with the `image_cropper` 1.5.0 version, and still same error ?

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, I had to restart my Android studio before the error was cleared.